# Addition in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

When in python3 I add 0.1 to 0.1, I get 0.2. But when I add 0.2 to 0.1 I get 0.30000000000000004.
What is the problem? How it works?

```
>>> 0.1+0.1
0.2
>>> 0.1+0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>>
```

Comment: Also mandatory [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: [0.30000000000000004 is an excellent search term](https://www.google.com/search?q=%220.30000000000000004%22)